# Facebook Messenger Send API returns #2022 error, although owner is verified

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

We are getting the following error in case of some Pages:

> "(#2022) You're restricted from acting as your Page until you complete
> Page Publishing Authorization. Switch back to your Primary Profile to
> complete authorization under - Settings - Account Settings - Identity
> Confirmation. Complete verification or you will be restricted
> indefinitely"

The mentioned Page Owner has already confirmed the "Identity Confirmation", which is present on this page: https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=account

Still, no luck. We have reported this on Facebook Bug Platform, and although the issue is assigned, we got no substantive answer from FB.

Has anyone experienced this error message and have tips/tricks how to resolve this? Any help would be much appreciated!